# Phonegap build Icon wont set

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap build to build my Android app and every time it defaults to the default phonegap icon when I install the APK.

In my xml file I have these lines:

```
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
```

I am assuming only the first line is refering to my app icon based on the documentation i have read. I have placed my icon.png in the root of my file but it never sets once built. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mike,
the root icon `<icon src="icon.png"/>` is a source of confusion. I can't give you answer on that. However, I have [working demos](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html)

You will want to try the Android [Splash Screen App](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1362035/share) to see if this works on your device. Notes are include with the [Source Code](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test).
Best of Luck.